# JavaFX tableView - overriding the behaviour of arrow keys

Tags: javafx, tableview, scrollpane

I'm trying to override the behaviour of arrow keys on a JavaFX 
tableView. I've managed to do it, but now I'm in trouble with the ScrollPane.

In short, I have a TableView with 3 columns (0,1,2) and pressing the right-arrow key from 2 I want the selection to move on 1 (not 0), on the next row. This is done.

But now I can't find a way to reset the Scrollpane when I get to the last row. With Swing, working on a similar project, I was able to do it.

Here is my SSCCE -- not so short, i know

```
package application;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

class TVScrollPane extends ScrollPane {

    public int row;
    public int col;

    public TableView<TableViewRecord> tableView;
        public TableColumn<TableViewRecord, String> tableColumnA;
        public TableColumn<TableViewRecord, String> tableColumnB;
        public TableColumn<TableViewRecord, String> tableColumnC;

    public TVScrollPane() throws Exception {

        /* set columns */
        tableColumnA = new TableColumn<TableViewRecord, String>("column A");
        tableColumnA.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableViewRecord, String>("columnA"));
        tableColumnB = new TableColumn<TableViewRecord, String>("column B");
        tableColumnB.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableViewRecord, String>("columnB"));
        tableColumnC = new TableColumn<TableViewRecord, String>("column C");
        tableColumnC.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableViewRecord, String>("columnC"));

        /* set tableView */
        tableView = new TableView<TableViewRecord>();
        tableView.getColumns().add(tableColumnA);
        tableView.getColumns().add(tableColumnB);
        tableView.getColumns().add(tableColumnC);
        tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        /* add records */
        ArrayList<TableViewRecord> al = new ArrayList<TableViewRecord>();
        for(int i = 0; i <= 20; ++i) {
            al.add(new TableViewRecord());
        }
        tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(al));

        /* row/column registration */
        if (tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().size() != 0) {
            row = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0).getRow();
            col = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0).getColumn();
        }

        /* set on actions */
        tableView.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    if (tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().size() != 0) {
                        row = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0).getRow();
                        col = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0).getColumn();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        tableView.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                    switch (e.getCode()) {
                    case RIGHT:
                        if (row < tableView.getItems().size()) {
                            switch (col) {
                            case 0:        col = 1; break;
                            case 1:        col = 2; break;
                            case 2: ++row; col = 1; break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    int r = row;
                    TableColumn<TableViewRecord, ?> tc = tableView.getColumns().get(col);
                    tableView.getSelectionModel().select(r, tc);
                    tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
                }
            }
        });

        /* set content */
        setContent(tableView);

    }

}

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void init() {}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage s) {
        try {
            s.setScene(new Scene(new TVScrollPane()));
            s.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

And this is the class for the tableView record description: it must be public and in a separate class file:

```
package application;

public class TableViewRecord {

    private static Integer tvRecordsCounter = 0;

    private String columnA;
    private String columnB;
    private String columnC;

    public String getColumnA() { return columnA; }
    public String getColumnB() { return columnB; }
    public String getColumnC() { return columnC; }

    public TableViewRecord() {
        ++tvRecordsCounter;
        columnA = "a_" + tvRecordsCounter;
        columnB = "b_" + tvRecordsCounter;
        columnC = "c_" + tvRecordsCounter;
    }

}
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to fix this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: why do you extend scrollpane? It's TableViewSkin (or more precisely: its flow) that manages the scrolling. As to default (and overridden) reaction to key strokes: that's the task of the behaviour - which is hidden api (even in fx9 or fx10) and requires some daring to replace .. without doing it, the behaviour will most probably interfere with whatever you are doing.

Comment: you're right: there's no need to extend ScrollPane. I used ScrollPane automatically, didn't know about TableViewSkin. So far, even removing ScrollPane, I didn't succeed but I'll do some other tests and post asap the solution or a new correct example without ScrollPane. Thank you @kleopatra

Answer (score 1):

Starting from kleopatra's suggestion I looked for a way to interact with the Skin scroll manager directly from TableView and found this nice scrollTo() method:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#scrollTo-int-

Here's a solution, with fixed height and number of visible columns

```
package application3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

class testTableView extends TableView<TableViewRecord> {

    public static final int TABLE_VIEW_HEIGHT = 350;
    public static final int VISIBLE_ROWS_NUMBER = 13;

    public int row;
    public int col;

    public TableColumn<TableViewRecord, String> tableColumnA;
    public TableColumn<TableViewRecord, String> tableColumnB;
    public TableColumn<TableViewRecord, String> tableColumnC;

    public testTableView() throws Exception {

        /* set columns */
        tableColumnA = new TableColumn<TableViewRecord, String>("column A");
        tableColumnA.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableViewRecord, String>("columnA"));
        tableColumnB = new TableColumn<TableViewRecord, String>("column B");
        tableColumnB.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableViewRecord, String>("columnB"));
        tableColumnC = new TableColumn<TableViewRecord, String>("column C");
        tableColumnC.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableViewRecord, String>("columnC"));

        /* set tableView */
        getColumns().add(tableColumnA);
        getColumns().add(tableColumnB);
        getColumns().add(tableColumnC);
        getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        /* add records */
        ArrayList<TableViewRecord> al = new ArrayList<TableViewRecord>();
        for(int i = 0; i <= 500; ++i) {
            al.add(new TableViewRecord());
        }
        setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(al));

        setPrefHeight(TABLE_VIEW_HEIGHT);

        /* row/column registration */
        if (getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().size() != 0) {
            row = getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0).getRow();
            col = getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0).getColumn();
        }

        /* set on actions */
        setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    if (getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().size() != 0) {
                        row = getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0).getRow();
                        col = getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0).getColumn();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                    switch (e.getCode()) {
                    case RIGHT:
                        if (row < getItems().size()) {
                            switch (col) {
                            case 0:        col = 1; break;
                            case 1:        col = 2; break;
                            case 2: ++row; col = 1; break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    int r = row;
                    TableColumn<TableViewRecord, ?> tc = getColumns().get(col);
                    getSelectionModel().select(r, tc);
                    if (r <= VISIBLE_ROWS_NUMBER - 1) {
                        scrollTo(0);
                    } else {
                        scrollTo(r - VISIBLE_ROWS_NUMBER + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

}

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void init() {}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage s) {
        try {
            s.setScene(new Scene(new testTableView()));
            s.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```